Synchronization TX and RX pulses in Pluto-SDR
I am currently working on implementing a FMCW radar for SAR application, I have successfully generated, transmitted, received the CWchrip. But when I move to the calculation of the beat frequency by multiplying the Tx and the Rx signals, the beat that I get is moving and not stable as it should be even though the target is stable.
As I read, I found that I need to synchronize the two pulses before beat calculation in order to get the perfect beat frequency. But I don't understand how I synchronize the two pulses.
After reading some papers I kind of got the Idea that I can use a correlator block in GNU radio to sync the signals I want to know how I can do that and if it can be done through software or I need to provide external clock pulse to the pluto sdr using arduino or something. I also saw a paper that said if you know the range you can add a particular delay to your Rx signal as the FPGA delay will be deterministic.
Below is my setup, the results that I am currently getting.


Link to the screen recording showing the moving beat frequency which should be constant for a stationary target.

please don't cross post this all over the internet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78291079/synchronization-tx-and-rx-pulses-in-pluto-sdr . Including the GNU Radio bug tracker, this is the  fourth place you posted this question, and nowhere do you tell the people who might read the question that you've posted it elsewhere, potentially duplicating effort.
